# Azure - Could not automatically scale because monitoring data was not found

Tags: azure, autoscaling, azure-diagnostics

We're using the autoscaling preview in Azure, but for the last few hours the portal has been reporting the following warning:

> Could not automatically scale "deployment name" because monitoring
>   data was not found

[image]

Clicking on the "details" button next to the warning just loads the scaling page.

On the "monitor" page there is no monitoring data available, the graph is empty.

[image]

I know the autoscaling  feature is in preview, but there isn't any way to report faults - unless you pay for a support option.

Is there anything we can do to fix this (other than deleting the deployment and re-deploying!) and how do we report the fault, preferably without paying!

Comment: We're currently experiencing the same issue as we speak. Hoping that Microsoft would officially say something about this error soon.

Comment: Can you check if you can see any up-to-date monitoring data metrics in other cloud services? For some reason I can't see metrics for the past hour on all my services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was seeing the same thing, but it seems to have caught up now. The metrics are only 10 minutes behind now. I have submitted a ticket with Microsoft but they haven't provided any extra information (yet) about the slowdown.

Comment: They're back now for me too. Be great if you could let me know what they come back with! Thanks

Comment: "The new metrics itself was implemented on the new portal and released a month ago. There are some items on which they are now directly connected to auto-scale and we are fixing it at this point...If you are using auto-scale with the new metrics implementation, the feature auto-scale is still in testing and we can’t provide SLA. The current metrics for the portal after the new portal implementation is being improved over time and we are seeing cases on what they can disappear and re-appear but it’s being handled for the next portal release in about a month away."

Comment: Well at least they've accepted there's a problem I suppose, and I guess autoscaling *is* still in preview after all. Thanks Jarvis - hopefully they'll be able to make it stable by the time it enters GA.